# Error when using read.gml or read.graph to read a GML file

Tags: r, gis, igraph

I am trying to load a file from the [spanish building census](http://www.catastro.minhap.es/INSPIRE/buildings/03/ES.SDGC.bu.atom_03.xml) (any of the files there will serve as an example, I'm using the 03001-ADSUBIA buildings one).

I have tried the read.gml function from the Multiplex package and get the following error:
`read.gml("A.ES.SDGC.BU.03001.building.gml")
Error in which(("node" == arx) == TRUE)[1]:which(("edge" == arx) == TRUE)[1] : 
  NA/NaN argument`

Then I tried the read.graph from the igraph package and also got an error:
`read.graph("A.ES.SDGC.BU.46900.building.gml", format=c("gml"))
Error in .Call("R_igraph_read_graph_gml", file, PACKAGE = "igraph") : 
  At foreign.c:1127 : Parse error in GML file, line 1 (syntax error, unexpected STRING, expecting $end), Parse error`

What am I doing wrong, and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an alternative [on this post](https://nehemie.github.io/2015/10/20/Read-GML-in-R/). However I would like to know why specific packages like multiplex or igraph cannot get the job done properly...

Code:

```
llayer<-ogrListLayers("A.ES.SDGC.BU.03001.building.gml")[1]
a<- readOGR(dsn="A.ES.SDGC.BU.46900.building.gml", layer=llayer, encoding = "UTF-8")
```

Answer (score 3):

`igraph` and `multiplex` do not work because that is a different GML: Graph Modelling Language, as the name suggests, is for graphs (or networks). Your GML is Geography Markup Language.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used GEPHI to open gml files, and then use GEPHI'S export function (menu driven) to create 'new' gml files that open with `igraph` in R.

Details about GEPHI and the gml file definition [are here](https://gephi.org/users/supported-graph-formats/gml-format/).

Comment: If you are aware of any GML files that Gephi can read but igraph cannot, _please_ report them to igraph: https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues/new/choose